# Finding how many isomorphic graphs are there

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many different graphs on the vertex set $V = \{1,2,...,n\}$ are isomorphic to:

[image: graph]

Answer for all $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ while $2 \leq k \leq n-3$.
Separate the cases when $n = 2k + 2$ and $n \neq 2k+2$.

My answer for the case of $n = 2k+2$ was $(n-2)! \cdot 2!$: 
$n-1$ and $n$ can change places and $1,2,...,k$ and $k+1,...,n-2$ can change places between themselves.

Comment: No. $(n-2)!$ is not what you want. Write that in terms of $k$ and translate to $n$ afterwards, if you want.

Comment: Every relabeling of the vertices is an isomorphism, and every isomorphism is a relabeling of the vertices. Some of these relabelings do not yield different graphs though.

Comment: Zackkenyon, what are you trying to say, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of graphs with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ isomorphic to your graph
(let's call it $T$) is $n!/|\mathrm{Aut}(T)|$, where $\mathrm{Aut}(T)$ is the automorphism group of $T$. (This is a consequence of the orbit-stabilizer lemma.)

In general the order of the automorphism group here will be the product of two factorials, but there is an exceptional case.